# Guitar Hero/Rock Band wireless keyboard

Tags: rock-band, guitar-hero

For some reason google is failing me...

There is a Guitar Hero/Rock Band wireless keyboard (or "keytar") made for 360, Wii, and PS3.

1. Are there multiple versions of this controller, or just one?
2. How do they connect to these three consoles?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple versions of the Rock Band 3 keyboard, which I hear are incompatible with each other.

- The Wii edition connects via a specific bundled USB receiver, which has two pass-through ports (and an obnoxious blinking blue light which blinks even when the system is asleep).
- *(anyone, feel free to edit PS3/360 info in here)*

Note that you can also use a standard MIDI keyboard rather than the specialized keybord using the "Rock Band 3 MIDI PRO Adapter", which is also console-specific. If you were feeling especially perverse, you could use that adapter together with the MIDI-out of a Rock Band 3 keyboard for a different console (but you'd have to use the buttons on the adapter).

Comment: My PS3 keyboard has what I assume is an identical receiver.  Really I think the only difference is the system-specific navigation buttons.

Comment: @Shinrai …and different wireless connection protocols. An Xbox keytar isn't going to pair with a Wii.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - A moot but valid point, since you can't manually pair with the receivers anyway there's no way to mix them up like that.   (Thankfully!)